# Why doesn't this "diary sexp" work?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, calendar, diary

I've inserted this entry:

```
%%(diary-anniversary 01 27 1948) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
```

in an .org file (that Emacs evaluates when I press `C-c a a`to obtain the agenda view) but in the agenda, on this week day (tomorrow, 01 27) the entry does not appear. What have I missed?

Comment: Even if you cannot use `C-c [` , the key sequence is bound to `org-agenda-file-to-front`  so you can *ALWAYS* use the extended command `M-x org-agenda-file-to-front` to do the same thing. This is used mostly for testing: it adds the file to the front of the current `org-agenda-files` list, so its contents are scanned in order to construct the agenda, If the file is already a member of that list, you do *NOT* need to add it.

Comment: Please stop adding spurious answers. All of the clarifications should be added to your questions and the spurious answers should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The two possibilities I can think of are: 1) you have not added the file to your `org-agenda-files` or 2) you have redefined `calendar-date-style` to use a different order from the default `month, day, year`.

To test the first possibility:

- start with `emacs -q`
- create an Org mode file with the following contents:

```
* Anniversaries
%%(diary-anniversary 01 27 1948) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
```

- save the buffer and add the file to the agenda list with `C-c [`
- create an agenda with `M-x org-agenda RET a`

Since you start with `emacs -q` you are not going to have `C-c a a` available to you - that's why I specified `M-x org-agenda RET a` above.

The entry should appear in the agenda, regardless of what you have done in your init file (since `-q` does not use it).

If you now start with `emacs` i.e. *with* your init file, visit the file you created above, add it to the agenda list and create an agenda with `C-c a a` (presumably the key binding is now available). If the entry appears, you are done: just make sure that the file is made part of your agenda list wherever `org-agenda-files` is initialized.

If not, check `calendar-date-style` with `C-h v calendar-date-style` where you will see:

```
Your preferred style for writing dates.
The options are:
‘american’ - month/day/year
‘european’ - day/month/year
‘iso’      - year/month/day
This affects how dates written in your diary are interpreted.
```

If you have set that to `european` e.g. you have to specify the date as `(27 1 1948)`.

The [Timestamps](https://orgmode.org/manual/Timestamps.html) section of the Org mode manual warns about this in a footnote:

```
   (2) When working with the standard diary expression functions, you
need to be very careful with the order of the arguments.  That order
depends evilly on the variable ‘calendar-date-style’.  For example, to
specify a date December 1, 2005, the call might look like ‘(diary-date
12 1 2005)’ or ‘(diary-date 1 12 2005)’ or ‘(diary-date 2005 12 1)’,
depending on the settings.  This has been the source of much confusion.
Org mode users can resort to special versions of these functions, namely
‘org-date’, ‘org-anniversary’, ‘org-cyclic, and ~org-block’.  These work
just like the corresponding ‘diary-’ functions, but with stable ISO
order of arguments (year, month, day) wherever applicable, independent
of the value of ‘calendar-date-style’.
```

I use ISO dates exclusively, so I prefer to use the suggested `org-anniversary` form:

```
%%(org-anniversary  1948 01 27) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
```

which is not affected by `calendar-date-style`.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I've solved... this two entry works fine:

```
%%(diary-anniversary 01 30 1948) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
```

or this

```
%%(org-anniversary 1948 01 30) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
```

both works well... maibe the prob was in the date format: this is not the format I've choosen for emacs. This is the format of this function.

Thank you all

Renato

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but it is not clear how: the only difference between the form in your question and the one in your answer is that the day is `30`, instead of `27`. Although Arthur might object to having his birthday shifted like this, that makes no difference to Emacs. So what exactly was it that resolved the problem?

Comment: you can use:
%%(org-anniversary 1948 02 01) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)

Comment: you can use:
%%(org-anniversary 1948 02 01) Arthur's birthday (%d years old)
or
%%(diary-anniversary 02 01  1948) Arthur's birthday (%d years old con diary)
the difference is on the date format.  YYYY MM dd (for org-anniversary)
MM dd YYY for diary-anniversary.
I still can't understand why I didn't get any error messages abot the wrong format, but emacs has just ignored the text (or maybe MY emacs is setted to not display error messages)

Comment: I know all this (as my answer clearly indicated). What is not clear is what was wrong, but it seems you don't know either: you did something and it fixed it but what exactly you did, nobody knows.

Comment: ... More or less like this. I tried many ways to let that be understood. The only one I have found is the one explained in the previous posts